# Finding the minimum value of $\frac{a^2+b^4+c^2}{abc}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the minimum value for $\dfrac{a^2+b^4+c^2}{abc}$ where $a,b,c$
> belongs to the positive numbers.

I tried to solve the numerator separately then to manipulate it using $abc$ but I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: you may want to detail what you mean by trying to manipulate the numerator using $abc$

Comment: i tried to find  an inequality involving a^2+b^4+c^2 >= x times abc. then if I could do that I mamight divide it by abc to get the result . but I am completely stuck

Comment: I can make this as small as I want: let $a = n, b = \sqrt{n}, c = n$, then your expression is $3n^2 / n^{5/2} = 3/\sqrt{n}$.  If this is homework I suspect you may have miscopied it.

Comment: @MichaelLugo The OP probably means that $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Comment: a,b,c belongs to positive real numbers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $x,y,z$ are positive real number number, Then minimum value of $\frac{x^4+y^4+z^2}{xyz}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661372/if-x-y-z-are-positive-real-number-number-then-minimum-value-of-fracx4y4)

Comment: no Aig see there are two variables with power  4 but in my question it is one. I think Sir Michael Lugo has got the answer correct.

Comment: @VincentBatens same logic holds for natural numbers, just replace $a=c=n^2, b=n$ and take $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Aig my trick doesn't work in that question.

Answer (score 4):

It's evident that
$$f(a,b,c):=\frac{a^2+b^4+c^2}{abc} \ge 0$$
The infimum $0$ cannot be reached. We can choose  $(a,b,c) = (L^3,L,L^3)$ and make $L \to +\infty$:
$$f(L^3,L,L^3) = \frac{2L^6 + L^4}{L^7}\xrightarrow{L\to +\infty} 0$$